# How many $4$-subsets of $S= \{1,2, \ldots,20\}$ contain no consecutive integers?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I am trying an assignment problem  which I am unable to think about.

> Question is -> How many $4$-subsets of $S= \{1,2, \ldots,20\}$ contain no consecutive integers?

I don't have any idea how to solve it.

Can someone please explain how to think about it ?

Comment: Try with a value smaller than $20$, start with $7$ ... how many ways ? ... now try $8$ ... keep going until you can guess a formula.

Comment: if you take $x<y<z<t$ from $S$ which no two of them are consecutive, then $4\le x+3<y+2<z+1<t$, likely you take 4 number from the set $\{4,5,...,20\}$

Comment: Please write titles that give the reader some idea of what the question is about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider any subset $(A,B,C,D)$ with $A>B>C>D$.

Define

$x_1 = 21-A$

$x_2 = A - 1 - B$

$x_3 = B - 1 - C$

$x_4 = C - 1 - D$

$x_5 = D$

$x_1 , x_2 , ... , x_5$ are all positive integer greater than or equal to $1$ and
$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 +x_4 + x_5 = 18$.

For every $(A,B,C,D)$ there is a unique $(x_1 , x_2 , x_3 , x_4 , x_5)$.

There are ${{18-1} \choose {5-1}}$ possible $(x_1 , x_2 , x_3 , x_4 , x_5)$, thus there are ${17 \choose 4}$ such 4-subsets.